# Slow computer after Unity8

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unity, gnome-terminal

last night I installed unity8, and then quickly realized it just didn't work so I proceeded to remove it. However now whenever I hit

**ctl+alt+T**

to open a terminal, it takes a decent amount of time to process. Before it was as close to instant as it could get (IMO). One other thing to note is that after trying to open the terminal I cannot use any keys for things like making the screen brighter or darker, or volume.

My hardware is as follows:

i7 2.4GHz

8G of ram

128Gb SSD

1Tb HDD

Comment: Open `~/.dmrc`, change 2nd line to `Session=ubuntu`. Save it, logout and see if it works.

Comment: when i open  '~/.dmrc' the second line is already 'Session=ubuntu' :/

Comment: Look at login screen, if there's a unity switch at name side . I think you purged unity, instead of unity8.

Comment: There are no switches. It just displays my name and then a spot to input my password